# Передача контекста класса в метод-обработчик

Tags: javascript

В метод-обработчик не получается передать контекст класса ( в данном коде, контекст метода-обработчика становится e = MouseEvent ). Пробовал также привязать и через IIFE и через .bind(this), ничего не работает. В чем заключается проблема?

```
export default class {

  constructor() {
    document.addEventListener('mouseleave', evt => this.isOutDocument(evt) )
  }

  sendWarning() {
    alert('Warning')
  }

  isOutDocument(event) {
    this.sendWarning;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Код в вопросе должен работать. Только надо добавить скобки к вызову функции.

```
isOutDocument(event) {
  this.sendWarning();
}
```

Comment: Да уж, что то со мной сегодня не то:D Спасибо за внимательность, это работает